# how to error_log(wp_login_url())

Tags: debug, wp-login-form

I am trying to confirm if a filter I have applied has changed the wp_login_url to the correct address. I just want to print out the result of wp_login_url somewhere I can see it.

```
if ( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'clean-login' ) ) {
        add_filter('login_url', get_permalink( $post->ID ), 10, 2);
        //$log_url = wp_login_url();
        error_log(esc_url(wp_login_url($redirect)));
    }
```

I have been playing round with printf echo and now error_log. Not a super experienced php guy and only just playing with the wp debug.log now.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is part of a hook 'save_post' so I have to edit and save the post every time I want to call this code and check for the log.

Answer (score 0):

I think, while saving the post, you won't be able to display this result.

You can try below instead -

Log the output in the database. 
e.g. `update_option('some_option', wp_login_url($redirect));`

And then print `get_option('some_option')` directly somewhere outside this `save_post` hook callback (e.g. on `wp_footer` hook). You may need to refresh the page after save post to see the result.

or rather just check directly in the `options` table of WordPress database to see the result.

Comment: Ran this and it created the key in wp_options table but no value.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the filter reference page for 'login_url'
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url

I realised I needed to use a function like so...

`add_filter('login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 2);
function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect) {
    return get_permalink( $post->ID );
}
error_log('login updated: '.wp_login_url($redirect));`

This worked fine with the debug.log